# how to check now() falls between two specific dates?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I've a announcement table with the structure,

```
Msgid int,
title varchar(150)
message text
date_from datetime
date_to  datetime
```

I've want to list all the announcements which will be due today (i.e) announcements of which today's date falls b/w date_from and date_to.

any ideas?

Comment: be sure to store the `date_to` values with a time of `23:59:59` if you want your message to show on the last day. renaming columns to `datetime_from` and `datetime_to` may reduce confusion ...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN date_from AND date_to
```

Comment: Indeed. And that's *usually* (but not necessarily always) more efficient than `WHERE NOW() >= date_from AND NOW() <= date_to`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT title, message
FROM announcements
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN date_from AND date_to
```