# SELECT MySQL rows where today's date is between two DATE columns

Tags: mysql, select

How can I get the rows in a table where today's date is between (inclusive) two DATE columns of that row?
For example, take these two columns of a table:

[image]

How could I get the first and second rows on the 10th of April, or the 3rd row on the 25th (inclusive, like I said)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: looks similar problem with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422576/how-to-check-now-falls-between-two-specific-dates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to check now() falls between two specific dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422576/how-to-check-now-falls-between-two-specific-dates)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You will find a lot of people using between operator, but I prefer using a simple AND operator.

I do that because although the between operator IS inclusive, simple dates (2012-04-10) can be counted as being midnight, and will thus not be inclusive.

So this should work just fine and will always include the boundaries of the date range:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE from_date <= '2012-04-10' AND to_date >= '2012-04-10'
```

Answer (score 31):

You can add a condition as follows

```
DATE(NOW()) between date1 and date2
```

Comment: also the solution

Answer (score 7):

Just use the SQL now() function to compare the date columns like so:

```
SELECT * from table where now() >= from_date and now() <= to_date
```

Comment: Use CURDATE() instead, Note that if you use NOW() it includes time information and can lead to exclude some dates, ie next function returns false (0):
    select "2010-01-01 14:00:00" <= "2010-01-01"

Answer (score 1):

If you have date (not datetime) columns, use CURTIME() or DATE(NOW()), never NOW() as CesarC correct wrote and you can use BETWEEN.

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE CURTIME() BETWEEN from_date AND to_date`